# Accessing environment properties in Application.doWithSpring()

Tags: spring, grails

I am adding a URL specific health check to my Application file, using doWithSpring().
I have the URL specified in an environment.properties file, and it is loaded into 'grailApplication.config.'

My problem is that 'grailsApplication' and 'config' have not been initialized yet.
How do I get to the values that will be located in these variables.

Can I move the health check creation to doWithApplicationContext()?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GrailsConfigurationAware interface to let grails inject grails configuration object into spring beans.

sample code

```
class HealthChecker implements GrailsConfigurationAware {

    def checkUrlHealth() {
    }

    @Override
    void setConfiguration(Config config) {
        // TODO with grails configurations
    }
}
```

And then register it as a spring bean by edit conf/resources.groovy

```
import chess_api.HealthChecker

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    healthChecker(HealthChecker)
}
```

Then after spring initialize the grails and your bean, the "setConfiguration" method will be called with grails configurations.

Be aware this method will not work for service, you have to explicitly register the spring bean.